# Display visitor count without authenticating with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I display visitor count to your web page without having to logging in or authenticating like Google Analytics?

I read their docs and found service account but the issue is that there is no full example of doing it written in JavaScript.

I tried this implementation.
However, there is no client_email in googleServiceAccountKey.

```
import google from 'googleapis'
import googleServiceAccountKey from '/path/to/private/google-service-account-private-key.json' // see docs on how to generate a service account

const googleJWTClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  googleServiceAccountKey.client_email,
  null,
  googleServiceAccountKey.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'], // You may need to specify scopes other than analytics
  null,
)

googleJWTClient.authorize((error, access_token) => {
   if (error) {
      return console.error("Couldn't get access token", e)
   }
   // ... access_token ready to use to fetch data and return to client
   // even serve access_token back to client for use in `gapi.analytics.auth.authorize`
})
```

I've tried examples with authentication buttons but I don't want users have to authenticate in order to see a page view count. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js

/* Non Google Analytics API*/
https://www.freevisitorcounters.com/
One example that counts every time user refresh the page which is wrong implementation.
http://javascriptexample.blogspot.de/2008/09/visit-counter.html

Does anyone know how to do this? Or other libraries or solutions are welcome too.

thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have a much better chance of getting help if you actually write something about what you have tried and what you actually want. A specific question related to a possible solution would be good, not "How can I do this". :)

Comment: I've edited the post and added what I've tried :)

Answer (score 0):

When using node.js you could do something like

```html
var server = http.createServer(app);    

server.getConnections(function(error, count) {

    console.log(count);

});
```